# passing information via javascript using php

Tags: javascript, php, json

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./js/laddubox.js"></script>
<script src="./js/pop.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sbs = {
         'url' : '<?="./gearedup-pics/"?>',
        'logged' : '<?=$notregister?>',
        'userid' : '<?= $id ?>',
        'father' : '<?= $father ?>' ,
        'mother'  : '<?= $mother ?>',
        'kid'  : "<?= $kid ?>"
        };
</script>
<title><?=$title?></title>
</head>
```

I am sending information via javascript using php but **$kid ,$mother and $father** are in array format . So its showing me an error.

**Notice:  Array to string conversion in **C:\xampp\htdocs\sbs\sbs\html\meta.php** on line **19**

Array' ,**

Comment: It is hard to tell why as we cannot see what you have actually in those variables. Try var_dump on them and see what format they are.

Comment: Shouldn't you really dump or echo those variables ?

Comment: Also, it would be easier to create an array in PHP, and just json_encode it !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<?=` converts the variable to a string and outputs it. Implicitly converting arrays to strings results in a notice (not an error).

I advise you to use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
<?php
$data = array(
  'url'    => './gearedup-pics/',
  'logged' => $notregister,
  'userid' => $id,
  'father' => $father,
  'mother' => $mother,
  'kid'    => $kid
);
?>
var sbs = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
```